# get all joined community sites under current site collection in search results/REST search/CSOM

Tags: search, sharepoint-online, search-results, rest, client-object-model

I've list of community sites in a site collection, and I have a publishing page on my site collection with a content editor WebPart on it. I've to show list of joined community sites on this webpart and I've a button "show more" at the bottom of the webpart, when i click on it I've to show a search result webpart which shows all joined community sites under current site collection. I'm trying use REST / CSOM on this content editor webpart. but i didn't find any way to do this.  any ideas?

Comment: What are "joined sites"? Why the need for a content editor, a Search or Query web part would be a better choice.

Comment: joined sites are the sites in which I clicked "Join this community" button on community site home page (member of the community). Even if I use search web part it is returning all community sites even if I'm not that community member. Is there any managed property to filter joined community sites.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I think I understand. There are a couple approaches you could take. Members of a Community Site are stored in the Members list. You can query the list with a KQL query like "`ContentClass:STS_ListItem_880  {User.Name}`" or "`MemberOWSUSER:{User.Name}`" this will return the Members list items from the sites. You could then trim the returned URLs to determine the associated sites. You might even be able to sort the return by the points you have on the site. That would be cool.

you could implement a result source of community sites or members to assist in narrowing your focus. It would add an interesting dimension to the query depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

You could add this query to a Search Web Part and apply a custom Display Template to render the Sites in a better presentation than the default item.

BTW, the default community sites search returns the sites you have access to, even if you are not a member because that is how search works in SharePoint. If you apply security to the sites it will prevent this from happening. The query is simply looking for the Community Site template.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'll try it. How can I sort the return by the points I have on the site? Sorting is also part of my requirement. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Add the Sort attribute to the managed property.

Comment: to which managed property. MemberOWSUSER?

Comment: I'm already using "ContentClass:STS_Web" to get only sites in results. Do I need to remove this and add "ContentClass:STS_ListItem_880 {User.Name}" and trim the URL. I used "{searchboxquery} contentclass:STS_Web AND Path:{Site.URL}* WebTemplate=Community AND People:{User.Name}" to get results

Comment: I would expect that you do. I only did a quick test. In my case I found it easiest to search for the Member records per your requirement. I would expect that ContentClass:STS_Web and ContentClass:STS_ListItem_880 would be mutually exclusive.

Comment: how about "{searchboxquery} contentclass:STS_Web AND Path:{Site.URL}* WebTemplate=Community AND People:{User.Name}" If i have People:{User.Name} I'm getting only two results. If I remove it I'm getting all community sites. I joined in other site but still I'm getting two results only(thinking it may take time to crawl). Do you think People is Correct property in this case.

Comment: If it's working for your test case then GREAT! In my case that query does not work. The People managed property in mapped to ows_People, Author and MailFrom none of those properties map to membership of the site.

Comment: Even if I use contentclass:STS_ListItem_800 it is not returning correct results. It returned a site which I'm not following. Even If I leave community the user entry is still there in Members list. If we goto "site/Lists/Members/MembersAllItems.aspx" it is showing only Active members. and "site/Lists/Members/AllItems.aspx" showing all members but "Member Status" property values is "2" for the user who leave the community.

Comment: Are you looking for "Following" or Members? Following is a totally different concept and is handled by the Social API. To improve your query add Member Status to your query.

Comment: Not for following sites. I'm trying to get the Community Sites in which I'm the active member, Even If I leave the community the site will be there in my Followed Sites right?. If I leave that Community I become inactive member. Then It should not be shown in search results.

Comment: Yes, "Following" is a totally different concept and easier to manage. How do you define "leaving the Community"? Determine that and adjust the query accordingly.